# Print a Blob or ArrayBuffer in IE (Angular 5)

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, pdf, printing

I'm working on an Angular 5 web application that should also work in IE. One of the features is to print a pdf, that isn't shown on the page (I'm using ArrayBuffer and Blob for this).

I have been able to do this in Chrome with an iframe, but that doesn't seem to work in IE.

Any ideas?